# How to send GPS to a android emulator

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator

How can I send simulated GPS positions to the emulator?
(This is not a repeated question because I have tried other solutions, don't work)

1) Opened the Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor
The Emulator Control Tab with the Location Controls are un Editable.

2) The emulator also has the "..." option which opens a control panel with Location. There I can see GPS data point and Send, but even if I do nothing changes to my program

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        }
```

3) If I have to use terminal, how do I know which port the emulator is attached.

I have used genymotion and it works well, except can not install google maps there yet.

Comment: can you try and open the Map app on the emulator and try if the location is updating there. Might be some problem with your configuration of the google maps api

Comment: Also dont forget to enable locations on the emulator, i think they are disabled by default

Comment: How do I enable locations on the emulator?

Comment: Like normal device- Settings -> Location

Comment: I am sorry. I don't follow you. Where are these? In Android Studio? The emulator? I can't find them

Comment: on the emulator, you can acces the settings like it is real device. Swipe down the status bar click on the wheel icon go to location

Answer (score 1):

to answer your third part of your question first:
the port your emulator is attached is written on top of your emulator window

There is written the name and afterwards the ports (default would be :5554)

[image: emulator_name_port]

To answer point one and two of your question:

to tell emulator fake gps data via command line you need to connect via telnet:

`telnet localhost <your emulator port>`

afterwarts it asks you for your auth token. the console will show you path where it is located. You need to enter the token via

[image: token_location]

`auth <your auth token>`

now you have a connection to your emulator and tell him whatever you want.

You can find a complete documentation of all commands at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

... or you type `help` into your console ;)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it tonight after work. Just one thing: the console will show me the path where I can find the auth token? in the command line you mean? Explain me this part a little bit more please

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know where to get this auth token. I don't know either which monitor you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I edited my answer and added some images. I hope it will help you, otherwise let me know ;)